# Finding running time of a simple linear recursive algorithm using recurrences

Tags: performance, algorithm, recursion, big-o, recurrence

If I had a simple recursive algorithm, such as:

```
numberOfMatches(A, x, i): // A is an array of values, x is a single value
                             the algorithm will search the array from A[1] to A[i]
count = 0
if i==0:
    return 0

if A[i]=x:
    count = numberOfMatches(A, x, i-1) +1
else:
    count = numberOfMatches(A, x, i-1)
return count
```

How would I go about finding the running time (which I know from common sense is O(n)) using recurrences?

I have got T(n) = T(n-1) because the list to be searched decreases by 1 each time, however, I don't think this is right.

I also need to solve the recurrence algorithm by expanding it, and I dont even know where to start with that.

Answer (score 0):

T(n)=T(n-1)+1
By induction you can prove it easily.